# On some pages don't show Menu Component but it is visible for a while

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to don' show Menu component on login and register pages. I created two layouts. One with Menu and second without. next I added meta to link in vue router

```
{
 path: "/login",
 name: "Login",
 meta: {
  layout: "NoMenu",
 },
 component: () =>
   import(/* webpackChunkName: "login" */ "../views/Login.vue"),
 },
```

And Here is function in App

```
<template>
  <Component :is="layout"></Component>
</template>
[...]
computed: {
layout() {
  return (
    this.$route.meta.layout || "Default") + "-layout";
 },
},
```

The problem is when I go to the login page Menu is visible for a while (less than one sec). I think this might happen, bcs vue-router loads synch and component is mounted before function gets this.$route. Any ideas to fix this showing menu for a while?

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is maybe `v-if`. From the documentation:

> The directive v-if is used to conditionally render a block. The block will only be rendered if the directive’s expression returns a truthy value.

If you use your component like this `<Component v-if="showMenu"></Component>` and set `showMenu` as a `boolean` data property initializing as `false`, you can determine when it should show.

This could be a state, when the user is logged in. As I understand you, you only want to hide the menu, when a user isn´t logged in. So this could be an approach for you.

Further informations: [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: That was the first idea I got, but doesn't work. I figured this out with help from some discord's group. The problem was $router is loading sync. And using v-if with $router is not good idea (Component loads before $router and this is why menu shows for a while). To fix this i used two different templates. One with menu and second without. In router i specified which path has to use which template

Comment: @Dawid Thats strange, because I´m doing exactly what you wanted in my own app, without a second template. And I can confirm that the component **doesn´t** render before the router is loaded.